# mapper_parsing_exception in Elasticsearch(Reason: No type specified for field [X])

Tags: api, elasticsearch, mapping, kibana

I wanted to provide explicit mapping to the fields in my document, So I defined a mapping for my index demo and It looks like this below:

```
PUT /demo
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
          "X" : {
            "X" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "Sub_X" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
    }
  }
}
```

After running the query , I am getting error as :

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "No type specified for field [X]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: No type specified for field [X]",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason" : "No type specified for field [X]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

The field X in json document looks like :

```
"X" : {
      "X" : [
        "a"
      ],
      "Sub_X" : [
        [
          "b"
        ]
      ]
    },
```

Please help me out with this elastic search mapper_parse_exception error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is called [nested data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)

You have `X` which in turn contains `X` and `Sub_X`.

**Mapping:**

```
{
  "properties": {
    "X": {
      "type": "nested"
    }
  }
}
```

**Data:**

```
{
  "X": {
    "X": [
      "a"
    ],
    "Sub_X": [
      [
        "b"
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

**Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "X",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "X.X": "a" }},
            { "match": { "X.Sub_X":  "b" }} 
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It outputs the document.